# Editing an answer (or question) can make it get more upvotes. Shouldn't the editor also get credit for these later upvotes?

Tags: discussion, editing, reputation

Editing can substantially change an answer or question. These changes, if accepted, may increase the value of the answer/question and the number the up-votes it gets. These should be reflected in the score of the editor making these changes, not only of the initial creator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editors get credit (at least those with less than 2000 reputation) by getting 2 points of reputation for each valid edit. In the end the original content came from the user. You just helped them improve it, fix it, or clean it up. If you're adding mountains of new information to the answer and want reputation, why not just add a new answer?

Comment: because i'm too generous? kidding. you gave a pertinent answer to a naive question. (in fact i use to ask questions to which i have an answer but than get other good answers. as i think it is better to have less but better answers, i edit those good answers, add my part of answering to these and now expect to get credit. in fact the question might get credit in this way.)

Comment: @cipricus At the end of the day rep is just a number that's fun to play with, remember the real value is improving answes for users so they can better use their computers, that's way more valuable!

Comment: off course, but when one has no chance to ever getting your rating any 2+ has something magical. of course you're right :)

Comment: @cipricus Also, feel free to ask and answer your own questions! Especially if you've experienced the issue and solved it yourself, or know it's a common problem. That way you'll get rep from a good question and a great answer