# Upvote the edits and remove the abbility over 3 answers

Tags: discussion

I recently came to this thought, because of an edit I did. Can we remove the ability over 3 answers and give to users the ability to upvote some edits as answers ? or maybe the editor could share an amount of reputation ? I don't mean [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4004/editing-an-answer-or-question-can-make-it-get-more-upvotes-shouldnt-the-edit). 2 points are not a share, just "chicken feed" :P

Also I don't like to see a question with 10-12 answers and all of them have upvotes (for one or another reason). It is more confusing for a new user. "What answer I should follow" ? Also the most upvoted answer is not always the best one. (imo).

The example of the edit I did and gave me this thought is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/398401/95393

Anyway and either way we follow I will follow this method and I suggest you to do the same. In above example I could easily add my own answer (more detailed) but no. One clear answer (maybe two or max three-no more) are better-clearer than 10 or 15.

Comment: Regarding many answers, follow them all in order of votes is what I do; but that may not be clear to new users...

Comment: Many different answers: that reflects real life. One symptom can be tackled in several ways, I have to choose. What I need is a way to weigh the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

1. your edit was massive. in my opinion, it would've been better as its own answer.
2. i have no idea what you're requesting.
3. also, your edit is prolly fine, just know that when you improve someone else's answer, you're contributing to the community without benefitting. this isn't bad!
4. it's only internet points..
5. five points are better than four.

Comment: I'm requesting to avoid situations [like this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: @NikTh I don't understand.. what situation?

Comment: 4)I don't really care too much about the Internet points, but I suggested that as an alternative if this idea could be happen.
@Seth . Too many answers. Too many answers (all upvoted and in this particular example an accepted answer does not even exist) are confusing. Too many answers can lower the quality of AU.

Comment: @NikTh Hm. I kinda understand what you mean. If you find duplicate answers you can flag them.

Comment: @Seth I don't speak about duplicate answers. I know that already. I speak about multiple answers in one simple question.